# change the keymapping under linux

Tags: linux, keymapping

### Target

make my system keymapping works in a way like vim;

```
I want the cursor move down  when pressing  windowsKey + j

I want the cursor move up    when pressing  windowsKey + k

I want the cursor move right when pressing  windowsKey + l

I want the cursor move left  when pressing  windowsKey + h
```

### Solution

```
Using xmodmap tool
```

### Result

```
Failed.
```

Here I'll give you some information:

I try to change the keymapping using this command under the shell

`xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"`

This command succeed, and the j and J is mapped to 1 and 2

But that's not enough,the windowsKey + j is not changed at all.

When pressing windowsKey + j, it gives me an 1 insted of 7

that's not what I want

### Specifics:

OS:Centos 6.4 (64 bit) with gnome 2.28.2

And the output of `xmodmap -pm`

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)

lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)

control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)

mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)

mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)

mod3      

mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)

mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

### Question

If there is other ways to change the keymapping or you can tell me where I'm wrong

Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reactions for keyboard events are specific for whatever programs are interpreting them.

If you're looking for a way to make command line editing work like vi, then you might get closer to what you want, with Bourne Again Shell at least, with `set -o vi` and then mapping the windows keys to escape (in order to enter vi edit mode) with `xmodmap -e 'keycode 133 = Escape' -e 'keycode 134 = Escape'`.

For other programs there are other ways to make this work, but cursor movement in v

Comment: I appreciate your answer.But I want the kepmapping works like vim not only in shell,but the whole X-Windows.

Comment: What you'd like to do is not possible with simply xmodmap as you'd like to remap a key combination, not just a single key.

Comment: So a driver layer customization is needed to reach this target?

Comment: XKBD might offer a possible path, but I have no real idea how to accomplish this with it.